# How to serve static index.html from meteor package

Tags: meteor, package

I trying to use package only structure for my app.
I created Meteor app like this:

```
meteor create appTest
```

Next i created new package Like this:

```
meteor create --package test-pkg
```

Removed all autocreated files and added one index.html in package.
And i changed package.js for my new files.

Next i added my package in meteor app

```
meteor add test-pkg
```

But after start app the index.html did not showed as default page
I tried to save this file in "client" folder in package but no luck.

If i placed this file in "client" folder at root app directory it works.

It's possible to serve static index.html from package?

My package.js

```
Package.describe({
  name: 'test-pkg',
  version: '0.0.1',
  // Brief, one-line summary of the package.
  summary: '',
  // URL to the Git repository containing the source code for this package.
  git: '',
  // By default, Meteor will default to using README.md for documentation.
  // To avoid submitting documentation, set this field to null.
  documentation: 'README.md'
});

Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.1.0.3');
  api.addFiles('client/index.html');
});

Package.onTest(function(api) {
  api.use('tinytest');
  api.use('test-pkg');

});
```

**EDIT**

I solved my problem by adding

```
 api.use('meteor-platform');
```

to package.js

Comment: Show us your `package.js` code.

Comment: I changed post - added package.js

Comment: Beware, it's still not a static page in the way people usually thinks about static pages. Actually, the solution you described only works by accident because Meteor parses your `index.html`, reads the `body` tag and puts it into the `Template.body` which is the "main" template to be rendered when your application is loaded. This is by no means a static page (look at the page source to verify it).